# not able to create the record in yii json api

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-rest

I am trying to learn yii and create an api. I am able to get the data but I am not able to create new record using my json object.

This is what I get

[image]

Here is my main.php in api config looks like

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],

    'components' => [

        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],

        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => '\common\models\User',
            'enableSession' => false,
            'loginUrl' => null
        ],

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'AH7T3J6-nwgUOF3DK_MYPhyzhhguo5-k',
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],



    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

As you can see I am setting up the json parser in request.

Here is the model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "room".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $floor
 * @property integer $room_number
 * @property integer $has_conditioner
 * @property integer $has_tv
 * @property integer $has_phone
 * @property string $available_from
 * @property string $price_per_day
 * @property string $description
 */
class Room extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'room';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['floor', 'room_number', 'has_conditioner', 'has_tv', 'has_phone', 'available_from'], 'required'],
            [['floor', 'room_number', 'has_conditioner', 'has_tv', 'has_phone'], 'integer'],
            [['available_from'], 'safe'],
            [['price_per_day'], 'number'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'floor' => 'Floor',
            'room_number' => 'Room Number',
            'has_conditioner' => 'Has Conditioner',
            'has_tv' => 'Has Tv',
            'has_phone' => 'Has Phone',
            'available_from' => 'Available From',
            'price_per_day' => 'Price Per Day',
            'description' => 'Description',
        ];
    }
}
```

For some reason its just not getting the json format.

I tried with form-data and it seems to work. But just raw json wont work

please have a look here

[image]

[image]

Comment: ` [['floor', 'room_number', 'has_conditioner', 'has_tv', 'has_phone', 'available_from'], 'required'],` these are required fields, make sure you are filling accordingly like datatype etc.

Comment: please check above...I am sending all required fields